# Determine active triangle based on X and Y coordinates

Tags: javascript

What is the mathematical formula that I would use to determine which triangle is active based on X and Y coordinates? From that I need to return `'bottom'`, `'top'`, `'left'` or `'right'`.

```
var x = 1;//horizontal coordinate (1~400)
var y = 1;//vertical coordinate (1~400)
var h = 400;//height of element
var w = 400;//width of element
```

[image: Triangles]

Either I have never learned such a formula or I do not recall learning it. The formula should work regardless of the element's dimensions (400x400, 400x200, etc). The top-left coordinates are 1 and 1. Absolutely no frameworks/libraries.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6syp528t/

Comment: This is actually a math question, not a programming one. If you are asking to help write code for you, in which case this is not allowed at all. On Stack Overflow, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** within the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a function that returns 0, 1, 2 or 3, denoting the triangle.

It is a bit odd that you say your coordinates start at 1, as the standard way would be to start at 0, which is also what is happening in the fiddle you provided in the question.

Here is the formula added to your fiddle, and a tooltip shows "top", "left", "right" "bottom" or "outside":

```js
function sideOfRectangle(x, y, w, h) {
    var side = (x * h > y * w) * 2   // +2 if at upper-right side of diagonal 1
          + ((w-1 - x) * h > y * w); // +1 if at upper-left side of diagonal 2
    return ["bottom", "left", "right", "top"][side]; // Convert to name
}

document.onmousemove = function(event) {
    var side = "outside";
    if (event.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'img') {
        var rect = event.target.getBoundingClientRect(),
            x = event.clientX - rect.x,
            y = event.clientY - rect.y,
            h = Math.round(rect.height),
            w = Math.round(rect.width);
        side = sideOfRectangle(x, y, w, h);
    }    
    showText(event.clientX + 10, event.clientY - 20, side);
}

function showText(x, y, s) {
    var tooltip = document.getElementById('output');
    tooltip.style.top = y + 'px';
    tooltip.style.left = x + 'px';
    tooltip.textContent = s;
}
```

```html
<img alt="400x400" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoDL4.png" />
<img alt="400x200" src="https://i.imgur.com/CctRt04.png" />
<span id="output" style="position:fixed"></span>
```

Comment: My current code is too convoluted to post, in a little while I'll update my question with a much more simplified example. Your code returns the following: 1113333222, 1111122222, 1111002222, 1100000022, 1000000002, 1333333332, 1133333322, 1113333222, 1111122222,1111002222, 1100000022, 1000000002.

Comment: What my code returns is in the snippet when you run it. It is not what you say. It starts with 1333333332.

Comment: I updated the snippet based on the fiddle in your question. It correctly shows the side the mouse is on for both images. Please have a look.

Comment: I would have been more than happy with just returning 'top','bottom','left','right'; interesting.

Answer (score 2):

Let's label the triangles as 1, 2, 3, 4 in clock-wise direction (starting with the top-most one). The simplest strategy would be probably to first transform into a coordinate system with origin in the middle of the triangle as:

```
xp = x - x0
yp = y - y0
```

where `(x0,y0)` denote the coordinates of the center of the rectangle.

Now, in this coordinate system, in order that the point is inside the square, we need `|xp| < w/2` and `|yp| < h/2`. Then to distinguish the triangles, the conditions are:

```
1: yp > |xp|
2: xp > |yp|
3: yp < -|xp|
4: xp < -|yp|
```

So in code, it could look like:

```
function testPoint(x, y, x0, y0, w, h){
    //recalculate coordinates with respect to the center of the rectangle
    var xp = x - x0;
    var yp = y - y0;

    var xpAbs = Math.abs(xp);
    var ypAbs = Math.abs(yp);

    //test if the point is in the rectangle
    if(xpAbs > w/2 || ypAbs > h/2) return 0;

    if(yp >= xpAbs){
        return 1;
    }else if(yp <= -xpAbs){
        return 3;
    }else if(xp > ypAbs){
        return 2;
    }else if(xp < -ypAbs){
        return 4;
    }
}


console.log(testPoint(2, 2, 2, 1, 4, 2)); //1 - i.e., the top-most triangle
```

Comment: I'm trying to work with it mentally and then try it in my code; are the single quotes to keep the visual formatting from breaking or for something else?

Comment: @John they just denote a different set of coordinates, perhaps it would be better to use something like `xp,yp` instead of the superscripts...

Comment: Personally I'd normalize all the coordinates so that they fall in the range `[-1, 1]`

Comment: It keeps returning 2 regardless of the coordinates. I'm working on a simplified test case that I'll post in a little while once I have it really simplified.

Comment: There's a problem with it. The return 1 and return 3 are opposite. https://jsfiddle.net/2kzLe2ca/ here's a working example

Comment: @JoaoLopes that depends on the orientation of the y-axis, the code above assumes that y increases upwards...

Comment: @ewcz yeah that makes total sense.

Comment: @John if the origin of the original coordinate system is not at the lower bottom corner of the rectangle, the formula for `xp,yp` has to be adjusted to take the offset into account...

Comment: Holy moly...I'm actually using a couple static image elements. I'm still working on my own Fiddle but I'm no where near as fast as you! I'm getting there though, no meal until I get it posted. :D

Comment: Fiddle added to the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure it's the mathematical formula you're looking for, but here's a solution with simple conditionnal blocks.

Meanwhile I decided to have some fun with SVG because it's been a long time :)

```js
var squareWidth = 100;
var squareHeight = 100;

document.getElementById("compute").addEventListener("click", function() {
  
  var x, y;
  x = parseInt(document.getElementById("x").value);
  y = parseInt(document.getElementById("y").value);
  if (x > squareWidth || x > squareHeight) {
   throw "X is too high!";
  }
  if (y > squareWidth || y > squareHeight) {
   throw "X is too high!";
  }

  var triangleId = wichTriangle(x, y);
  
  fade("1");
  fade("2");
  fade("3");
  fade("4");
  
  highlight(triangleId);
});

function wichTriangle(x, y) {

  if ((x+y) < squareWidth) {
  if (x > y) {
   return 1;
  } else {
   return 2;
  }
  } else {
  if (x > y) {
   return 3;
  } else {
   return 4;
  }
  }
  
 }
 
 function highlight(triangleId) {
  document.getElementById(triangleId).style.fill = "yellow";
 }
 
 function fade(triangleId) {
  document.getElementById(triangleId).style.fill = "grey";
 }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
</head>
<body>

X : <input type="text" id="x" value="50"/><br/>
Y : <input type="text" id="y" value="20"/><br/>
<button id="compute">Which triangle?</button>
<br/>


<svg height="100" width="100" id="shape">
  <polygon points="1,1 100,1 50,50" style="fill:grey;stroke:black;stroke-width:1" id="1"/>
  <polygon points="1,1 1,100 50,50" style="fill:grey;stroke:black;stroke-width:1" id="2"/>
  <polygon points="100,100 100,1 50,50" style="fill:grey;stroke:black;stroke-width:1" id="3"/>
  <polygon points="1,100 100,100 50,50" style="fill:grey;stroke:black;stroke-width:1" id="4"/>
  
  
</svg>

</body>
<script src="index.js"></script>
</html>
```